# WPF close a dialog when a bool changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I have some simple code in a C# WPF application, using [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) that pops up a `please wait` type of dialog.

What I want, is for the Dialog to close automatically when a boolean value changes (from a background thread).

I have:

```
//create dialog
var view = new Dialog
{
    DataContext = new Domain.DialogViewModel("Please wait...", true)
};

//show
var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ClosingEventHandler);


//wait
while (finished == false)
{

}

//close dialog, or enable the 'ok' button on it.

DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand.Execute(view, view); //does not work.
```

How can I close the Dialog from code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the DialogHost stuff you're using, but your question is fairly straightforward otherwise. You'll have a Task that runs on a background thread and then switches back to the UI thread when it's time to close the wait dialog.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

...

void StartLengthyTask() {
    var dlg = CreateWaitDialog();
    dlg.Show();

    // run lengthy task in a background thread
    Task.Run(new Action(BackgroundThread))

        // switch back to UI thread when finished
        .ConfigureAwait(true)
        .GetAwaiter()

        // close the wait dialog
        .OnCompleted(() => dlg.Close());

  // logic here will execute immediately without waiting on the background task
}

void BackgroundTask() {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, what i needed was to override the `OpenedEventHandler`. Using this:

```
 var view = new Dialog
            {
                DataContext = new Domain.DialogViewModel("")
            };

            //show the dialog
            var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ExtendedOpenedEventHandler, ExtendedClosingEventHandler);
```

I can grab the session in a function, such as:

```
   private void ExtendedOpenedEventHandler(object sender, DialogOpenedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            //...now, lets update the "session" with some new content!
            eventArgs.Session.UpdateContent(new ProgressDialog());
            //note, you can also grab the session when the dialog opens via the DialogOpenedEventHandler



            //lets run a fake operation for 3 seconds then close this baby.
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
                .ContinueWith((t, _) => eventArgs.Session.Close(false), null,
                   TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
```

and then close the dialog when i wish using:

`eventArgs.Session.Close(false)`.